# Bluetooth HDP android 4.0 really works?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am testing HDP profile for android 4.0. I think that it doesn't works correctly because, I am trying with Nonin 9560BT and it connects but it doesn't sends medical data to android.

The trouble is the next:

First, I init bluetoothAdapter and I getProfileProxy.

After, device connects to android. I catch `ACL_CONNECTED` with broadcastReceiver.
I ask for `bluetoothHealth.getMainFD` to open communication but it says Proxy not attached to service.

Finally, device disconnected.

Somebody can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Since people are asking questions regarding HDP source, A&D has made it public on github,
please find it here:
https://github.com/andengineering/A-D-HDP-Android-Demo

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me with A&D UA-767PBT-C without using Channel Connection, because the device connects automatically.

Comment: Hi how do you do to work? it doesnt work for me. And it doesnt connect automatically. I have to force connection with connectToSource

Comment: @Raul: shoot me an email @ czheng@andonline.com, I'll share the source code with you.

Comment: Hi @colorblue is the code for the 767PBT-C compatible with a 321PBT-C ?
In that case I'll be grateful if you can share some insights on that with me. 
[MY EMAIL](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/mailhide/d?k=013s8zto3RFVHnGU9QYajwjQ==&c=rdl-RDA8JABtWjEFXutiiXyPvTjJNqNHmauu9DsCfH4=)

Comment: @colorblue, could you also help me out with that? I will write to your e-mail, if you have the source code.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get the BluetoothHDP sample to work, but I had to pair the phone and the UA-767PBT-C and add the following code:

```
else if (prevState == BluetoothHealth.STATE_CHANNEL_CONNECTING && newState == BluetoothHealth.STATE_CHANNEL_CONNECTED) {
    if (config.equals(mHealthAppConfig)) {
        mChannelId = channelId;
        sendMessage(STATUS_CREATE_CHANNEL, RESULT_OK);
        (new ReadThread(fd)).start();
    } else {
    sendMessage(STATUS_CREATE_CHANNEL, RESULT_FAIL);
}
```

to `BluetoothHDPService.onHealthChannelStateChange()`.

After this I have harvested the code I could use from the sample and modified it to match my program.