# Using Bluetooth HDP Profile in Motorola Droid Razr M

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, motorola-droid

I have a Motorola Droid Razr M. I want to write an app that connect my phone with a health device using Bluetooth HDP profile.

Android 4.0 platform API supports HDP profile. BUT the specification of Droid Razr M shows that it doesn't support HDP profile: http://developer.verizon.com/content/vdc/en/verizon-devices/pages/mot_droidrazr_m.html

So it is impossible for me to run my app on this phone, isn't it?

Anyone's help would be appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Just download the android BluetoothHDP sample and Try. By the way, you have to adjust the codes:

```
else if (prevState == BluetoothHealth.STATE_CHANNEL_CONNECTING && newState == BluetoothHealth.STATE_CHANNEL_CONNECTED) {
if (config.equals(mHealthAppConfig)) 
{
    mChannelId = channelId;
    sendMessage(STATUS_CREATE_CHANNEL, RESULT_OK);
    (new ReadThread(fd)).start();
} 
else 
{
        sendMessage(STATUS_CREATE_CHANNEL, RESULT_FAIL);
}
```

to BluetoothHDPService.onHealthChannelStateChange().

More information:
[Bluetooth HDP android 4.0 really works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522190/bluetooth-hdp-android-4-0-really-works)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.stackoverflow.com/faq) for more info.